# Codeigniter global variables in a core controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using **$langs** Variable in my Core Controller.
How to use Global Variables in Codeigniter? i'm very newbie on CI

My Controller Code is :

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
  //global items
  var $langs;
  // construct
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    global $title;
    $langs = array(
      'en' =>'English',
      'zh'  =>  '繁體中文',
      'zh_CN' =>  '簡體中文',
      'fr'  =>  'français',
      'de'  =>  'Deutsch',
      'ja'  =>  '日本語',
      'es'  =>  'Español',
      'pt'  =>  'Português',
      'ru'  =>  'Русский',
      'tr'  =>  'Türkçe',
      'kr'  =>  '한국어'
    );
  }
```

My View Code is :

```
<?
//display
var_dump($langs);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    //global items
    public $langs;
    public $title;
    // construct
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $langs = array(
            'en' =>'English',
            'zh'  =>  '繁體中文',
            'zh_CN' =>  '簡體中文',
            'fr'  =>  'français',
            'de'  =>  'Deutsch',
            'ja'  =>  '日本語',
            'es'  =>  'Español',
            'pt'  =>  'Português',
            'ru'  =>  'Русский',
            'tr'  =>  'Türkçe',
            'kr'  =>  '한국어'
        );
        $this->langs = $langs;
    }
}
```

Use it in controllers that are extending MY_Controller as `$this->title` and `$this->langs`.
If you need it more widely available even if request controller doesn't extends MY_Controller, make own library with similar code and autoload it. Pay attention on making libraries. In docs it is well explained (check that [Example_library](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html#utilizing-codeigniter-resources-within-your-library)).